# QL decomposition

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I've read about the $QR$-decomposition, so I wonder is there an algorithm that does the factorization ${A = QL}$ of ${A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m \geq n$, such that ${Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is orthogonal and ${L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ has the following form
$$
{L} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{{L}} \\
{0}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\bar{{L}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a lower triangular matrix. If it is impossible can you explain the reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$QR$-decomposition is a consequence of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.
You could orthogonalize columns of $A$ starting from the last with lower triangular matrix.Then you would have to append columns to it to make it square and orthogonal.
So $Q$ wouldn't be unique.